# Is it possible to change the entire display string of a browser address(navigation) bar without postbacks?

Tags: javascript, url, web, browser, client-side

I know it is possible in modern browsers ( with HTML5 support) to replace the last portion of the URL using replaceState/pushState (example below) but I would like to change the entire display text in the address bar rather than the last portion.

*If it is possible could someone please provide an example.*

Example

```
<input id = 'button1' type = 'button' value = 'history.replaceState' onclick="updateHistory()"/>

<script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function updateHistory() {
        var stateObject = { 'Website': 'www.MashPotatoe.com};
        window.history.replaceState(stateObject, "Potatoe", "www.potatoe.com");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I very much hope and suspect that this is _not_ possible.  It would be horrible for security and allow a site to pretend to be a completely different site.